# How can I change google accounts associated to GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I have 2 google accounts ABC and DEF.
I usually use account ABC.
But now, I want to send Gmail from GAS as a account DEF.
And Gmail from GAS is send by the script author account.
So I want to make a script as account DEF.
However, when I try to create a new script on GAS dashboard logged in with account DEF, it is created as a account ABC´s script.
How can I send Gmail as account DEF from GAS?

Comment: `However, when I try to create a new script on GAS dashboard logged in with account DEF, it is created as a account ABC´s script.` Logout of ABC and sign in to DEF in a incognito tab and create a script.

Comment: You might also be able to set DEF as an [Alias](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()) on ABC's gmail settings, and send it that way